# Paypal HERE (= swipe card) and Adaptive payments?

Tags: credit-card, paypal-adaptive-payments

For our mobile application payment we want the user to be able to swipe the credit card. 
To achive this can I use PayPal Here API in conjunction with Adaptive Payments API = Classic API? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/pph-sdk-overview/

Could not find in the developer guide if Classic API is compatible https://github.com/PayPal-Mobile/android-here-sdk-dist/tree/master/docs

Answer (score 1):

Contacted PayPal support and they answered:
*So far it isn't possible to use PayPal Here with Adaptive Payment.
Payment Here is used only as a direct credit card processing, nothing combined with our actual API.*

Also asked if PayPal Here is working with any mobile SDK. They answered:
*The payment is executed by the Paypal HERE SDK.
See https://github.com/PayPal-Mobile/ios-here-sdk-dist/blob/master/docs/DeveloperGuide_iOS.pdf p20
You can't "synchronize" it with any other PayPal mobile SDK.*

So the products are not compatible.